# Запрос SQL (подстановка)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Довольно простое условие, до исполнения которого так и не могу дойти :с

Есть 2 таблицы: Дома и Квартиры.
В каждой из них есть поля "Номер дома" и "Улица". Нужно, чтобы в поле "Номер дома" таблицы "Квартиры" выводился список значений, у которых этот номер соответвует выбранной улице, обращаясь к таблице "Дома".

Т.е. если в таблице "Дома": 12 - номер дома, Калинина - улица, то в таблице "Квартиры": Калинина - улица, а номера домов выводятся те, что на улице Калинина в таблице "Дома".

Если более понятней, то задумка была такой:

```
SELECT Номер дома
FROM Дома
WHERE Улица = ...(значение улицы, назначенное в таблице "Квартиры")...
```

Очень наивный вариант... Я только-только изучаю эту сферу, и хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли такое, не несу ли я бред, и есть ли в SQL сравнение значений из других таблиц. Делаю в MS Access. Благодарю за любую помощь в данном вопросе!

Comment: *В каждой из них есть поля "Номер дома" и "Улица".* Это неправильно. В таблице Квартира достаточно ссылки на запись (поле со значением ID) из таблицы Дом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твой запрос нужно переписать как 
`SELECT Номер дома FROM Дома WHERE Улица = "любая улица"` , никакая информация о квартирах тут не нужна.

Вот пример где нужно в запросах использовать две таблицы :

```
SELECT КВАРТИРЫ.НОМЕР_КВАРТИРЫ , ДОМА.УЛИЦА FROM КВАРТИРЫ<BR> 
INNER JOIN КВАРТИРЫ.ID_ДОМА = ДОМА.ID <BR>
WHERE ДОМА.НОМЕР_ДОМА = 37 ;
```

---

В таблице "КВАРТИРЫ" такие поля как "номер дома" и "улица" лишнее. Думай о таблицах в твоей БД как о реальных объектах. Ведь в реальном мире у конкретной квартиры нет ни номера дома , ни названия улицы. Поля "номер дома" и "улица" могут быть только у дома, т.к. только у дома они есть в реальном мире. Таблицы ДОМА и КВАРТИРЫ должны связываться с помощью ключей между ними будет отношения `one to many`. Соответственно `foreign key` у таблицы ДОМА должен ссылаться на `primary key` таблицы квартира. В select'ах через join'ы работаем с этим таблицами.

В общем гугли как проектировать свои таблицы в БД и как их правильно связывать.